# What is the proper way to open a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on a mac and I can't figure out why I'm getting

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flying_circus_cast.txt'
```

with the following snippet of code. The text file is in the same directory as the python file.

I've also tried `./flying_circus_cast.txt` too but I get the same error

```py
def create_cast_list(filename):
    cast_list = []
    #use with to open the file filename
    #use the for loop syntax to process each line
    #and add the actor name to cast_list
    with open('flying_circus_cast.txt', 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

    return cast_list

cast_list = create_cast_list('flying_circus_cast.txt')
for actor in cast_list:
    print(actor)
```

Comment: you probably have a current directory issue. Check the current directory by printing `os.getcwd()`. Use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get current module path

Comment: Thanks Brian. That worked.